# Circular dependent generics - Unchecked cast?

Tags: java, generics

I tried to modulate the MVC pattern by using a generic approach. However I get an unchecked cast.
Else it seems to lead me in a loop where I have `Presenter(View(Presenter(View(...`

Is it possible to bypass this?

```
public interface View <P extends Presenter>{

    P getPresenter();
}

public abstract class Presenter<V extends View> {

    public void bind(V view) {
    }
}

public abstract class ViewImpl<P extends Presenter> implements View<P> {

    public void onStart() {

        getPresenter().bind(this); // unchecked cast!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public abstract class ViewImpl<P extends Presenter<View<P>>> implements View<P>
```